# TabLayout set spacing or margin each tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I want to set margin in between each tab. Like in PagerTabStrip which has setTextSpacing(int textSpacing) to make text spacing between tab. Can TabLayout do that?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Been fighting this problem for a while too, found the solution on this thread : [Android Design Support Library TabLayout using custom tabs layout but layout wrapping the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889672/android-design-support-library-tablayout-using-custom-tabs-layout-but-layout-wra?rq=1)

```
<!-- Add the padding to tabPaddingStart and/or tabPaddingEnd -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_layout_height"
        app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp">
```

Comment: Its also removes space between tabs (which are default) if you set paddings to 0. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a dynamic way for that?

Comment: Not that I know of, just double checked the TabLayout source code, and it looks like it's only through XML.

Comment: by default it adds padding - use app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"  app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp" if you want no padding

Answer (score 17):

You can use tabMinWidth attribute.
like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/default_enable"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/font_default_03"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/default_enable"
    app:tabMinWidth="50dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" />
```

Comment: Aww it was clipToPadding that helped me out to position the indicator but still have a big clickable area

Answer (score 15):

You can remove weight and set `marginEnd`,`marginStart` and `width` for tabs in `TabLayout`.

**kotlin:**

```
val tabs = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup

for (i in 0 until tabs.childCount ) {
       val tab = tabs.getChildAt(i)
       val layoutParams = tab.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
       layoutParams.weight = 0f
       layoutParams.marginEnd = 12.dpToPx()
       layoutParams.marginStart = 12.dpToPx()
       layoutParams.width = 10.dpToPx()
       tab.layoutParams = layoutParams
       tabLayout.requestLayout()
}
```

**java:**

```
ViewGroup tabs = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
       View tab = tabs.getChildAt(i);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tab.getLayoutParams();
       layoutParams.weight = 0;
       layoutParams.setMarginEnd(12);
       layoutParams.setMarginEnd(12);
       layoutParams.width = 10;
       tab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
       tabLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: you should call tabLayout.requestLayout() after for-loop for better performance

Comment: I get indicator in the tabs.getChildAt(i)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

When you wanted to achieve something like this for your `TabLayout` then follow this steps:

**1. Layout XML Code:**

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_5"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabIndicator="@null"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />
```

**2. Tab Background Drawable Selector (`drawable/tab_selector`):**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" />
</selector>
```

**3. Drawable of `tab_background_selected` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:left="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:right="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:top="@dimen/dp_5">

        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/btnBG" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_10" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**4. Drawable of tab_background_unselected :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:left="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:right="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:top="@dimen/dp_5">

        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_10" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 8):

layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

java

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
int betweenSpace = 100;

ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);

for (int i=0; i<slidingTabStrip.getChildCount()-1; i++) {
    View v = slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    params.rightMargin = betweenSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

if anyone has custom background for tabs(selector), you just need add layer list to tabs background and set margin for them

selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected_tab" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_unselected_tab"/>
</selector>
```

selected tab:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="8dp" android:left="8dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/Green"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/cardCornerRedius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

unselected tab:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="8dp" android:left="8dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/Gray"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/cardCornerRedius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 5):

When you set tabPadding not working , you can try set tabMaxWidth and tabMinWidth. It is work for me.

```xml
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:tabMaxWidth="200dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="20dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMinWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        />
```

Comment: By default android gives some minWidth, becasue of this there will be some minimum width for each tab. If you want to give width as wrap_content then give minWidth="0dp", and if you want space between tabs then give tabPaddingStart="10dp" and tabPaddingEnd="10dp" as per your requirement

Comment: This is wat worked for me. None of the other answers!!

Comment: wanted tabs to be at equal space when tablayout width is fixed and       app:tabMinWidth="0dp" worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answers are shown to help if the distance between the tabs is assumed to be the same.

But there are times when you need the last tabs to stand apart from the others (at the end of the view). So, you can not create a menu for a toolbar (and not create a toolbar), and use a common tab indicator for everything.

Unfortunately, you cannot directly set paddings and margins for each tabitem, but you can create a fictitious one more tab item and control the distance through attributes:

app:tabPaddingStart
app:tabPaddingEnd
app:tabMinWidth
app:tabMaxWidth

Although this is a bit of a crutch solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `app:tabMinWidth` fix the issue and you can then adjust padding using `app:tabPaddingStart` , `app:tabPaddingEnd`, but without adding `app:tabMinWidth` nothing got reflected.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tabs"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/bg_color"
                            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                            app:tabMode="scrollable"
                            app:tabMinWidth="50dp"
                            app:tabPaddingStart="8dp"
                            app:tabPaddingEnd="8dp"
                            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_323232"
                            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance"
                            app:tabTextColor="@color/color_cecece" />
```

Answer (score 0):

app:tabMode="fixed"
to
app:tabMode="scrollable"

Comment: if your text not fited on tab and text

Answer (score 0):

1- Add "tabBackground" attributes in your tablayout xml view

2- Put this shape as a background and add stroke width as per your spacing requirements and set its color to transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/app_theme_color" />
<stroke
    android:width="8dp"
    android:color="@color/transparent" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how set margin for four different tabs. You can change the setMargins(v1,v2,v3,v4) function values to get a suitable fitting for the number of tabs that you are working with. I hope this helps.
Please note that tabHost is the object of TabHost hosting different tabs you are working with.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            int width = display.getWidth();
            View currentView;
          for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
            {
                //This code removes divider between tabs
                tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(new
                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/8)-2,50));
                 currentView = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams currentLayout =
                      (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) currentView.getLayoutParams();
                  currentLayout.setMargins(30, 5, 80, 0);

            }
```