# Android - Custom Tab Layout with CHIPS style?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, tabs

How do I achieve this look in my tabs?
[Image describing the style I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqmX4.png)

I want it to:

• change the color of the text depending on the page viewed (I achieved that already through the default supportLibrary's Widget TabLayout)
• change the color of the background stroke
• have spacing between each tab element (could not achieve that through the padding option)

Is there a library that could help me, I searched but haven't got to any useful details, in fact, I don't know what to type in the search bar.
What is the name of this style?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for that you need to set custom tab to TabLayout

Comment: I am also trying to achieve same thing. I customized tab drawable, and other things. The only pending thing is margin between chip. I will Add my code within some time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

Most part is xml customization.

**style.xml**

```
<style name="ChipTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/selector_tab</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Create following **drawables**:

1. chip_outline.xml
2. chip_outline_selected.xml
3. selector_tab.xml

**chip_outline.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#B1BCBE"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding
            android:left="16dp"
            android:top="8dp"
            android:right="8dp"
            android:bottom="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

**chip_outline_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#B1BCBE"/>
    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#B1BCBE"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

**selector_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_outline_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_outline_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_outline_selected" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_outline" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_outline" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_outline" android:state_activated="false"/>
</selector>
```

**toolbar xml code**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="4dp">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                style="@style/ChipTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="30dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:minWidth="80dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Utils.kt**

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        fun dpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
            return ((dp * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt());
        }

        fun pxToDp(px: Int, context: Context): Int {
            return ((px / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt());
        }
    }
}
```

[Java alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38841669/3843374)

Add following code **after** tabLayout.setupWithViewPager() in your activity / fragment:

```
for (i in 0 until binding.toolbarHolder.tabLayout.getTabCount()) {
        val tab = (binding.toolbarHolder.tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(i)
        val p = tab.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        p.setMargins(Utils.dpToPx(8), 0, Utils.dpToPx(8), 0)
        tab.requestLayout()
    }
```

[Java alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817987/3843374)

Change colors as per your requirement. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are the best.

Comment: Hi @Paritosh and thanks for your solution. The only problem I have is that the ripple of clicks on the tab goes out of the shape (its rectangle). Any ideas?

Comment: @Alator I will check for the fix