# How to add margin between tab backgrounds inside tab layout android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, tabs

2 tabs having separate backgrounds with border and there should be distance between those to backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can add those two attributes:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
...
app:tabPaddingStart="10dp" 
app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp" />
```

I found the same question before and you can find the answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511524/9040853

I hope you find my answer is useful.

Comment: thanks for answering but I want individual backgrounds for two tabs. "tabPadding" adds space but in Single tab layout with one background not two separate background for two tabs.

Comment: Do you mean that you want one background for both tabs. One background and above of it the tabs right?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32613364/9040853 I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,
Keeping views like this(that tick) on top of another view is called `Overlapping Layouts`, you can do it by using relative layout, the gallery view and image view will overlap

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/gallerylayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/overview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/navigmaske"
    android:background="#0000" /*use #000000 for black colour*/
    android:src="@drawable/navigmask" //put your image here
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/overview"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/overview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965641/14862885)